# How to redirect all incoming http request to a specific url in nginx config file?

Tags: http, spring-boot, nginx, server, redirect

I know , I know. This question is asked too many times and I've researched it alot as well. But every solution on internet lead me to dead end.
I want to redirect all the incoming http-request to a specific url/domain.
For example if someone type - `www.test.com` or simply `test.com` in browser's url-bar, it should redirect the user to `http://test.com/home` .
This is what I've been trying to achieve from last 3 days, not sure what I'm doing wrong.
 This is my server-block.

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name test.com;
        port_in_redirect off; 
     #  server_name_in_redirect off; 
        client_max_body_size 20M; 

 location / { 

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For
      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_redirect off; 
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8000/ ;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;     
      return 301 http://test.com/home;

        }

}
```

This above configuration is giving me error - `too many redirection` on browser when I'm trying to access the website.Also removing `return` statement giving me `page not found` error and not changing/redirecting the url to `http.test.com/home`.

**PS - I'm running another different website as well on this same server on port 443(https) & that is working absolutely well. I'm running a Spring-boot application. 

A help is highly appreciated.**

Comment: Did u try this - `location ~ ^/$ {
      return 301 http://test.com/home;
    }` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well ,it ends giving `404 Not Found` error on browser.

Answer (score 0):

You write too many codes related to redirection, that's why showing this error.

Change your server block like below.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name test.com www.test.com;
    client_max_body_size 20M; 
    #return 301 http://test.com/home$request_uri;
}

location ~ ^/(?!home) { 
  return 301 http://test.com/home$request_uri;
}

location /home {
    root   /var/www/test.com/html/;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I tried your approach , but it shows the same error on every browser `too many redirects` , `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` . Tried clearing browser's caches & cookies as well. Also, after pasting this code it is redirecting on a url `test.com/home/home/home/home/home/home` too many times.

Comment: @sumit I understand, what's wrong. just try above code

Comment: This is giving us error -  `this site can't be reached`

Comment: @sumit, it showing because here you only redirecting to another location, but not serving any data for `/home` URL, you need to add one more location to serve data.

Comment: Again it is creating the url on `test.com/home/home/home/home/home/home` with `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`